# How Can I Run a Function Inside of Views.py and Print Result? -- Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

The problem is that I am trying to call a function from my views.py and print the result in my template through a context variable. The function prints in the terminal and does not work in the template. I posted a question a few days ago regarding doing this with subprocess, but I still could not figure it out.

How can I print "This is a test function for AAPL" in my template instead of in the terminal?

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render  
from backtests.scripts import Backtests

def index(request):

    if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol','Invalid Symbol')
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol
    else:
        symbol = request.session['symbol']


    earnings_object = Backtests("AAPL")
    test = earnings_object.print_discrep()


    return render(request, 'backtests/earnings.html', {'symbol':symbol, 'test':test})
```

**scripts.py**

```
class Backtests:

    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol

    def print_discrep(self):
        print('This is a test function for the graph ' + self.symbol)
```

> It is returning None in my template.

Comment: Please post your template code

Comment: I figured it out. I had to put return in my scripts.py instead of print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function in the view. To call it in the template, assign the function object, not the result of the function call:

```
test = earnings_object.print_discrep  # no ()
```

Update:
`print` prints to the command line, not into your template.

The template displays the return value of functions you call. Your `print_discrep` doesn't have a return value, defaulting to `None`.

If you want to display data in the template, return that data in your function:

```
def get_discrep(self):
    return 'This is a test function for the graph ' + self.symbol
```

Then you can call the function either in the view or in the template.

Comment: Hmm I am still getting none. Is this object variable not being recognized for some reason?